# Python Flask: clicking button doesn't do anything

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask and I'm trying to build a simple web app. Basically what I have on the home page is a text input box and a submit button.

After clicking submit, it shows some result based on the text that was inputted (for now it's hardcoded in the code below) and also 2 buttons (positive/negative) to add the inputted text to a specific file (either with a "positive" or "negative" label).

However, the problem I face is with these 2 buttons: they don't do anything when clicked.

Here is what I have for now:

## The Python Flask app

```
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/process-data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process_data():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # get the text from the form that was filled in
        input_text = request.form['text']

        # if submit button is clicked
        if request.form['submit'] == 'Submit':
            final_result = 'stackoverflow is the best'

        if request.form['submit'] == 'Positive':
            f = open('dataset/dataset.tsv', 'a')
            f.write(input_text + '\t' + 'positive')

        # if negative button is clicked  
        if request.form['submit'] == 'Negative':
            f = open('dataset/dataset.tsv', 'a')
            f.write(input_text + '\t' + 'negative')

        # show the result on the page   
        return render_template('index.html', result=final_result, text=input_text)
```

## The index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<form action="/process-data" method="post" role="form">
    <label for="text">Text:</label>
    <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Input sentence here">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

{% if result is not none %}
    {{ result }}
    <h2>Add to dataset</h2>
    <form action="/process-data" method="post" role="form">
        <label for="add-dataset">This sentence was:</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Positive">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Negative">
    </form>
{% endif %} 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your `/` route and have it simply return the index template and nothing else like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Then assign the other route to another function which will do the processing. I wouldn't call it index, maybe something like process-data, like this:

```
@app.route('/process-data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def process_data():
    # put the body of your function here
    # ...
    # ...
    # ...
    return render_template('index.html', result=final_result, text=input_text)
```

Finally, you just need to update your form action accordingly:

```
<form action="/process-data" method="post" role="form">
```

Comment: I tried your solution but now it says "local variable 'input_text' referenced before assignment". How do I pass the variable from one form (i.e. the first form with the text box and submit button) to the second form (the positive/negative buttons which are used to write input_text to a file with a label)?

Comment: I would need to see the body of your `process_data` function to know what you're doing incorrectly.

Comment: I edited my initial post with the new code. Can you check please?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have set the configuration setting `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE`. If you're working in localhost or through an unsecure line and you have set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True` then no session cookie will be sent and as such no forms, csrf protection and various other operations will work. Instead use `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=False` under these circumstances.